# Diversity Bronze Badge Idea

Tags: feature-request, badge-request

I was thinking maybe it would be good to offer a badge for those that have a minimum score of 1 across 50 tags.  Perhaps this would help get user's to read/answer questions on other tags more often, instead of just camping in the high-traffic ones trying to get upvotes...

Comment: That's an interesting idea, but it is just too tempting to throw hit or miss answers at tags I am barely competent in until I get a single upvote. The segregation of answerers into tags relevant to their area of expertise isn't necessarily a bad thing.

Comment: 50 tags is way too low of a threshold. You don't need to be _active_ in many tags just to have activity in different tags, you just need to be active period. Most questions will have other tags tacked onto them, not just the one you're interested in.   I primarily hang around the [c#] and [knockout.js] tags and have gotten "votes" for many other tags as well just because the questions I've been active in had those tags added as well.

Comment: 50 tags and one bronze. I dont have much reps still i have 1+ upvotes in 350 tags.

Answer (score 11):

A large number of questions have one or two relatively irrelevant tags in addition to the more popular ones. This makes it fairly easy for a user to rack up scores on these tags, even if they never branch out from the high-traffic tags. So just requiring 1 upvote on *any* 50 tags is pretty bad, IMO.

Instead of just upping the number of tags or upping the upvote requirement, I think you should restrict the tags to a more relevant subset. This might make for a decent bronze-level version of the **Generalist** badge, if it were changed to something like:

> Provided non-wiki answers of 1 total score in 50 of top 200 tags

This would make it a far more interesting badge, as well. Users would be forced to target a specific set of tags. It would drive many of them to visit the *Tags* page to see what tags count toward their goal—and hopefully find areas where they can provide more quality answers in the process.

I also think *diversity* is not quite the right name. If it's a bronze-level version of **Generalist**, perhaps [**Versatilist**](http://www.wordnik.com/words/versatilist) might be a better term, but who knows…

---

I took the liberty of running some very crude simulations, just for comparison:

- Using OP's original spec, [typical users who would earn the badge would do so at around 1.8K rep](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/113781/would-be-diversity-badge-winners#graph).
- Using my modified spec, [typical users who would earn the badge would do so at around 8.0K rep](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/113796/would-be-diversity-badge-winners-alternate#graph).

Of course, this looks at current behavior patterns. One would expect if either spec is implemented, many users would try to get the badge earlier, bringing the average rep down. Similar analysis suggested the typical user who earns the **Generalist** badge does so at around 25K.

Comment: Your points about a score of 1 are completely valid; I don't quite understand why you went on to suggest exactly the same thing... I have a score of more than 1 in almost 300 tags; it's guaranteed that I fulfil the conditions of this. I only have a score of 5 (for e.g.) in 86 tags though... seems more reasonable.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards My point was not that it's too easy to get 1 score, but that it's too easy to get it *many* irrelevant tags. If the goal is to encourage users to explore other areas of the site, then making it just any 50 tags doesn't accomplish that. Sure you could bump the limit up, but still I don't feel that properly encourages, users to look for areas they can contribute--they're likely just to search for questions in tags where they have a score of 4, whether or not that tag is actually useful to future users. I think this is the same rationale underlying the **Generalist** badge.